# Python Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in the ubuntu playbook

Tags: python-2.7

I wanted to make s3 bucket for the user in AWS Console using the python playbook when I imported botonew.py and it gave me the Syntax Error as

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file botonew.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Here is the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlku5.jpg